# ipad implementation of board games with strong AI

Tags: computer-ai

I sometimes enjoy playing some board games like ticket to ride or settlers of catan on my ipad. In most cases I prefer to play against the AI, because it allows me to pause the game and continue at a later time. However, the AI-players in the games I played are kind of weak and I lose interest after playing a couple of times.

Now I would like to buy a new game but with a competitive AI. I prefer games for 3-4 players with a length of less than 2 hours. Can you recommend something?

Comment: I find the AI in Ascension to be capable, but that could just be a revelation that the game is more random and more winnable with consistent application of 'best play' rules than the designers would like to admit :)

Comment: I have to strongly disagree with the comment regarding Ascension. The AI is very predictable after a few plays

Answer (score 1):

Agricola from Playdek offer a good challenge. And you can play single or the serie mode against yourself.

Elder Sign , Summon War and Yggdrasil are also good choice.

More depend of the game theme that you like ?